# Help Getting Started with Mechanize

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and just installed Ruby for Windows.
I want to use the mechanize library (https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize) and so I'm following the guide at https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize/blob/master/GUIDE.rdoc.

On the Windows cmd line, I installed mechanize by using the cmd "gem install mechanize".

When I run the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
```

I get the error:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- net/http/digest_auth (LoadError)
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mechanize.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from helloworld.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that some dependencies are missing. Try to install the `net-http-digest_auth` gem.

> gem install net-http-digest_auth

If that solves this problem and another (related) pops up, it's probable that you are missing the `net-http-persistent` gem. If that's the case, you know what to do! Just install it too.